# Enter button keypress in Puppeteer

Tags: keyboard, keypress, puppeteer, enter

I am working on [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) and using [keyboard](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagekeyboard).
I get stuck when typing some destination in search box then I find.
There are two action:

1. `await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown');`
2. `await page.keyboard.press('Enter');`
   Then I got result: 
   [Image when search location using api Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d35TA.png)

Problem is 'Enter' button seem not really working with the suggest destination when the code  `await page.keyboard.press('Enter');` run. It **can not** find **this destination** by auto.

But I tried to search by manually, 'ArrowDown' press and 'Enter' press, then I can find the destination by manually.

Can you help me find out solution and solve it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you check which type of keyboard your Puppeteer uses? According to their docs, you can find all the keys in [this file](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/USKeyboardLayout.js)

Comment: 'Enter': {'keyCode': 13, 'code': 'Enter', 'key': 'Enter', 'text': '\r'}, in Doc
I use 'code' to run `page.keyboard.press('Enter');`

Comment: Every search input field has a button / icon you can click on to initiate the search. So instead of asking the keyboard to press `Enter` why not just use `await page.type()` to enter your text as normal and then click on the icon?

Comment: But I need the actions run automatically on the page :(
That's reason why I used puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP seems to want to have the Enter keypress not go to the original search field, but to the DIV of postal addresses that Google Maps generates in response to his Puppeteer bot typing the first few letters of a street name or similar. So he wants to confirm a Google Maps search suggestion.

So the solution is to first type in a few letters into the search field, scan the DOM tree anew, to find that DIV that appeared in response to the keypresses, then press arrow down until the desired entry is selected, and send the Enter keypress to it, instead of sending it to the original Search  field.